# Show the following relation:

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

In order to follow a proof (Hobson's Introduction to General Relativity, section 3.9) I need to show that:

$$\frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^d}\frac{\partial^2 x^d}{\partial x'^c\partial x'^b}=-\frac{\partial x^d}{\partial x'^b}\frac{\partial x^f}{\partial x'^c}\frac{\partial^2 x'^a}{\partial x^d\partial x^f}$$

In the book it's argued as "swapping derivatives..." but I feel like I'm missing some step here, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try to differentiate $\frac{\partial x'^{a}}{\partial x^d} \frac{\partial x^d}{\partial x'^{b}} = \delta_{ab}$ with respect to $x'^{c}$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... But I don't really see how that would help my purpose

Comment: Use product rule...

Comment: Ohhhhh dammit I slept on it and now I see it, thanks!!